# ImportError: No module named flask.ext.socketio: DIGITS installation error

Tags: caffe, pycaffe, nvidia-digits

I have already installed `flask-socketio`,

when I try to run digits, it is showing me the following error

```
digits/webapp.py:7: ExtDeprecationWarning: Importing flask.ext.socketio is deprecated, use flask_socketio instead.
  from flask.ext.socketio import SocketIO
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/sam/anaconda2/envs/testcaffe/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 174, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
  File "/home/sam/anaconda2/envs/testcaffe/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
    exec code in run_globals
  File "/home/sam/DIGITS/digits/__main__.py", line 70, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/sam/DIGITS/digits/__main__.py", line 55, in main
    import digits.webapp
  File "digits/webapp.py", line 7, in <module>
    from flask.ext.socketio import SocketIO
  File "/home/sam/anaconda2/envs/testcaffe/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/exthook.py", line 110, in load_module
    raise ImportError('No module named %s' % fullname)
ImportError: No module named flask.ext.socketio
```

How to solve this? thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can do: sudo apt-get install python-flaskext.socketio

After that error you would probably have this other error:
ImportError: No module named flask.ext.wtf
That you can fix by:
sudo apt-get install python-flaskext.wtf

Probably the best you can do is install all dependencies by using the requirements file proper from digits.

pip install -r requirements.txt